# Unable to assign strings to bool results in async tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario like that:
I have async task method, in this method there are 3 jobs included and they all  return boolean results (true/false). The main goal of this code is to create a single JIRA issue if all three jobs return `false` value (this part works pretty well), but if there are one or two `false` results out of three, it should create **two** (in case of 2 falses) separate JIRA issues.

Here's a code:

```cs
public static async Task TaskArray(string urlTypeId, int ID, string l)
{
    async Task<bool> t1()
    {
        bool result = true;

        try
        {
            FindElement(driver, SelectorTypes.ByXpath, "xpath");
        }
        catch { result = false; TestResult(ID, ErrorText(1), driver, urlTypeId, l); }

        return result;
    }

    async Task<bool> t2()
    {
        bool result = true;

        try
        {
            FindElement(driver, SelectorTypes.ByXpath, "xpath");
        }
        catch { result = false; TestResult(ID, ErrorText(2), driver, urlTypeId, l); }

        return result;
    }

    async Task<bool> t3()
    {
        bool result = true;

        try
        {
            FindElement(driver, SelectorTypes.ByXpath, "xpath");
        }
        catch (Exception e) { result = false; (ID, ErrorText(3), driver, urlTypeId, l); }

        return result;
    }


    //Creating ticket(s)
    {
        Task<bool> bee = t1();
        Task<bool> geo = t2();
        Task<bool> mag = t3();

        if (await bee == false && await geo == false && await mag == false)
        {
            // all results are false, creating 1 ticket

            CreateTicket(ID, GErrorText(4), driver, urlTypeId, l, "Main", "Desktop", "Website", "SB", "All");
        }
        else
        {
            //1 or 2 false result(s) create ticket for each false   
            var BooleanArray = new bool[] { await bee, await geo, await mag };
            var NamesArray = new string[] { "John", "George", "Nick" };

            foreach (Boolean value in BooleanArray)
            {
                if (value == false)
                {
                    CreateTicket(ID, ErrorText("string"), driver, urlTypeId, l, "Main", "Desktop", "Website", "SB", NamesArray[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the last `else` I'm trying to:

1. Get amount of `false` results;
2. Identify which one(s) return false result out of three ("bee", "geo", "mag");
3. Go to `foreach` and create a JIRA ticket, which will pass right ErrorTexts as one of the parameters and also it will get a right string from `NamesArray`

I know this is too complicated, so I will provide an example of the full scenario below:

1. If all three jobs return value `false`, it creates one ticket (as I already mentioned before, this case works fine);
2. If there are 2 `false` results out of three, it goes into the last else and completes `foreach` twice (since we have 2 false results). On each enter into foreach, the parameters that are passed to `CreateTicket` method, is not static, but dynamic. For example: If "t1" and "t2" return false result, the following operation must be completed:

> CreateTicket(ID, ErrorText(1), driver, urlTypeId, l, "Main", "Desktop", "Website", "SB", "John");

and then

> CreateTicket(ID, ErrorText(2), driver, urlTypeId, l, "Main",
>   "Desktop", "Website", "SB", "George");

I hope I will find a help or a hint here, I'm already trying to resolve this problem couple of weeks but I still couldn't find a proper way to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var results = await Task.WhenAll(bee, geo, mag);` `if(!(results[0] || results[1] || results[2])) { create single ticket } else { if (!results[0]) { create ticket "John"} if (!results[1]) { create ticket "George"} if (!results[2]) { create ticket "Nick"} }`.

Comment: `var names = new List<string>(); if (!(await bee)) names.Add("John"); if (!(await geo)) names.Add("George"); ...` ?

Comment: If you want to associate a string with a boolean result, it would be better to combine them into a single data structure, but even with the structure you have, if you were to switch to a `for` loop you would have your index directly. You can rig a foreach loop to give you the index but it will look clunky, but the least clunky solution would be `int index = 0; foreach (...) { ... code here ; index++; }`.

Comment: I still don't know where you have an error or issue. You describe code, but not an issue. Additionally I don't know how you get j value which is used inside foreach.